# Getting the SDL_Color of a single pixel in a SDL_Texture

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I am having some problems finding a solution on how to retrieve a specific color of a pixel on a SDL_Texture...
To be bit more specific: I am trying to calculate the average amount of color used in a given texture. Later on I want to devide for example the number of red pixels by the total amount of pixels. For this task I will need a method, which will get me each pixel color...

I tried to search for some functions, but unfortunately I wasnt able to figure it out..
I saw methods like SDL_RenderReadPixels and SDL_GetPixelFormatName, but none of those helped me out...

Do you have a solution for me?

Comment: Average amount? Do you mean average color? Why didn't `SDL_RenderReadPixels()` work? You need to show us some actual code you have tried and what went wrong before we can help.

Comment: I meant "total amount of pixels filled with a specific color".

Comment: @olevegard: thanks for the reference to `SDL_RenderReadPixels`! Just what I wanted.

Answer (score 6):

To access an SDL_Texture's pixels, you must create a blank texture using SDL_CreateTexture() and pass in SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING for the access parameter, then copy the pixels of a surface into it. Once that's done, you can use the SDL_LockTexture() function to retrieve a pointer to the pixel data which can then be accessed and modified. To save your changes, you'd call SDL_UnlockTexture(). Try something like this:

```
SDL_Texture *t;

int main()
{
    // Init SDL 

    SDL_Surface * img = IMG_Load("path/to/file");
    SDL_CreateTexture(renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA8888, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING, img->w, img->h);

    void * pixels;

    SDL_LockTexture(t, &img->clip_rect, &pixels, img->pitch);

    memcpy(pixels, img->pixels, img->w * img->h);

    Uint32 * upixels = (Uint32 *) pixels;

    // get or modify pixels

    SDL_UnlockTexture(t);

    return 0;
}

Uint32 get_pixel_at(Uint32 * pixels, int x, int y, int w)
{
    return pixels[y * w + x];
}
```

You can get the colors from a pixel like this:

```
Uint32 pixel = get_pixel_at(pixels, x, y, img->w);
Uint8 * colors = (Uint8 *) pixel;

// colors[0] is red, 1 is green, 2 is blue, 3 is alpha (assuming you've set the blend mode on the texture to SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND
```

If you want more information, then check out these SDL 2.0 tutorials: http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/index.php. Tutorial 40 deals specifically with this problem.

Let me know if you have any questions or something is unclear.

Good luck!

Comment: Is this still accurate? I note [the `SDL_LoadTexture` documentation](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_LockTexture) today states: _lock a portion of the texture for **write-only** pixel access_, and _As an optimization, the pixels made available for editing don't necessarily contain the old texture data. This is a write-only operation, and if you need to keep a copy of the texture data you should do that at the application level._

Comment: user2437378, you are memcpying data to a void pointer (pixels) without allocating any memory (in advance)! Can you explain this?

Comment: @user1511417 Yes that's undefined isn't it? I can only guess that they were trying to make it quick and so incomplete - assuming that the OP would do that. But that seems silly to me since there's no code in the question itself. This answer makes me think of here's the concept but you still have to do it. Since the question provides no code maybe it's fair enough but it would be nice if the answer pointed this out.

Comment: Found out at https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_LockTexture, that the previous `SDL_LockTexture`-call provides write-only access to `pixel`. So this should be fine, assuming that SDL is doing the job right concerning memory etc. *But* the return value of that call is definitely ignored here in this example. This is also the case in *tutorial 40* on lazyfoo.net. :(

Comment: I can't see how this answer would be safe; pixels needs to be set to a reserved section of memory with malloc or calloc. Otherwise, even if it compiles, it will consistently write out of bounds and have difficult-to-trace side effects.

Comment: SDL_LockTexture updates the pixels pointer to point at the texture data. If you allocated memory first, you would leak that memory.